# how to get list of files stored in a .qrc Qt Resource file with QML?

Tags: qt, qml

If one wanted to do it from C++, one can do:

```
QDirIterator it(":", QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
while (it.hasNext()) {
    qDebug() << it.next();
}
```

However, if I wanted to do the same from within QML / Javascript, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it with a `FolderListModel`. Here I modified the example found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-folderlistmodel-folderlistmodel.html#example-usage) to show everything in the resource table.

```
    ListView {
        width: 200; height: 400

        FolderListModel {
            id: folderModel
            folder: "qrc:/"
            nameFilters: ["*"]
        }

        Component {
            id: fileDelegate
            Text { text: fileName }
        }

        model: folderModel
        delegate: fileDelegate
    }
```